# Bootstrap panel heading styling not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I have a little problem with CSS styling. For some reason which I can't determine this won't style correctly and I can't edit the colour in CSS. Here is an image to what the actual header looks like and for some reason the background won't style.

[image]

Here's my css styling code for the class that it's using:

```
.panel-heading {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ececb0;
}
```

Here's my html code for the header:

```
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="title">DeadSwitchand</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `!important` over the `background-color` property:

```
.panel-heading {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ececb0 !important;
}
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/735pc/)**

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect.